# Query to Boost and Sort the data in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

Good day team...

I have a requirement to fetch(if address contains 'US;') the US employees first in Sorting order(By ename), followed by the remaining employees in sorting order (By employee name). Please help me to prepare es query.

My sample sample json records are..

```
{
    "employee" : {
        "ename": "John",
        "address": "U001; US; NewYork" 
    }
}
{
    "employee" : {
        "ename": "Andrew",
        "address": "U001; US; NewYork" 
    }
}
{
    "employee" : {
        "ename": "Phillip",
        "address": "U002; UK; Readings" 
    }
}
{
    "employee" : {
        "ename": "Michel",
        "address": "U002; UK; Readings" 
    }
}
```

and my expected result will be...

```
{
    "employee" : {
        "ename": "Andrew",
        "address": "U001; US; NewYork" 
    }
}
{
    "employee" : {
        "ename": "John",
        "address": "U001; US; NewYork" 
    }
}
{
    "employee" : {
        "ename": "Michel",
        "address": "U002; UK; Readings" 
    }
}
{
    "employee" : {
        "ename": "Phillip",
        "address": "U002; UK; Readings" 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an index and add esp. the `keyword` data types:

```
PUT employees
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "employee": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "ename": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          },
          "address": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Sync:

```
POST _bulk
{"index":{"_index":"employees","_type":"_doc"}}
{"employee":{"ename":"John","address":"U001; US; NewYork"}}
{"index":{"_index":"employees","_type":"_doc"}}
{"employee":{"ename":"Andrew","address":"U001; US; NewYork"}}
{"index":{"_index":"employees","_type":"_doc"}}
{"employee":{"ename":"Phillip","address":"U002; UK; Readings"}}
{"index":{"_index":"employees","_type":"_doc"}}
{"employee":{"ename":"Michel","address":"U002; UK; Readings"}}
```

Sort first by the occurrence of `US`, then by the `ename` in alphabetical order:

```
GET employees/_search
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "_script": {
        "script": "return doc['employee.address.keyword'].value.indexOf('US') > -1 ? 1 : 0",
        "type": "number",
        "order": "desc"
      }
    },
    {
      "employee.ename.keyword": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

It's advisable to split the address into components before the sync and then boost the `US` country component instead of scripting your way to a solution.

Comment: Thanks for your response joe, It is working exactly what I expected.

Comment: I'm glad if it helped. If it did, please upvote & accept the answer.